# Legend not working properly when plotting pandas datafile

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have 3 different data sets, all of which have the same variables. The first data set is a control, the second is slightly perturbed except pressure, and the last is slightly perturbed, except pressure as well. I read these in using pandas and created a plot. However, the legend is not working properly. It shows each line as pressure, when I want them to all be temperature in their respective color. I would also like to be able to edit them to say 'Temperature (control), and so forth. Here is my code and plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
control=pd.read_csv("Control.csv")
control.columns=['Pressure', 'Temperature', 'specific humidity', 'buoyancy of air lifted from the lowest model level', 'relative humidity', 'convective heating rate', 'radiative heating rate', 'turbulent heating rate', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g','cloud fraction','h', 'i', 'j', 'k' ]
albedo_only=pd.read_csv("Albedo 0.2.csv")
albedo_only.columns=['Pressure', 'Temperature', 'specific humidity', 'buoyancy of air lifted from the lowest model level', 'relative humidity', 'convective heating rate', 'radiative heating rate', 'turbulent heating rate', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g','cloud fraction','h', 'i', 'j', 'k' ]
albedo_ocean=pd.read_csv("Albedo 0.2 Ocean 0.8.csv")
albedo_ocean.columns=['Pressure', 'Temperature', 'specific humidity', 'buoyancy of air lifted from the lowest model level', 'relative humidity', 'convective heating rate', 'radiative heating rate', 'turbulent heating rate', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g','cloud fraction','h', 'i', 'j', 'k' ]


ax=control.plot(x='Temperature', y='Pressure', kind='line', legend=True, 
title='Atmospheric Temperature')
albedo_only.plot(x='Temperature', y='Pressure', ax=ax)
albedo_ocean.plot(x='Temperature', y='Pressure', ax=ax)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.xlim(-80, 30)
plt.xlabel('Temperature (C)')
plt.ylabel('Pressure (hPa)')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward solution, avoiding going into matplotlib, would be to do e.g.

```
albedo_only.plot(x='Temperature', y='Pressure', ax=ax, label='Albedo only')
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was something simple I was missing.